# binary pdf byte[] to com.lowagie.text.Document

Tags: java, itext

I had an binary pdf(Byte []). I would like to convert it to a com.lowagie.text.Document.is there anyway to convert it without losing any information on it.Thanks

this is i tried, and to not sure how to move further.

```
                Document  document  = new Document();
                PdfWriter writer =  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
                document.open();
                PdfReader  reader = new PdfReader(byteBuffer);
```

Comment: What you can do is open it as a `PdfReader`. You only have a `Document` when creating a new document.

Comment: yes. I tried that .but wondering how write a byte[] in a document.There are no methods available to serve.

Comment: A `PdfReader` is there for *reading* a PDF. If you want to manipulate it and store the results (to disk or to memory), you need a `PdfStamper`. Have a look at [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action, 2nd edition](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/). The samples for iTextSharp can be found [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx) and those for iText [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php).

Comment: By the way: please don't use my name in your code. Upgrade to itextpdf: http://lowagie.com/itext2